# Why does functools.cmp_to_key() give me a Type Error on comparison?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I was doing some coding interview problems when I ran into this error. I'm trying to use functools.cmp_to_key() function to use my comparison function, but when it reaches the sorting step, it gives me `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`.

Please disregard the fact that my code is probably not solving the problem correctly -- I'm really just curious why that error is appearing.

```py
from typing import List
import functools

def comparison(a: str, b: str):
  print((a, b))
  if len(a) == 0:
    return b
  elif len(b) == 0:
    return a
  elif a[0] < b[0]:
    return a
  elif a[0] > b[0]:
    return b
  else:
    return comparison(a[1:], b[1:])

class Solution:
  def largestNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> str:
    cmp = functools.cmp_to_key(comparison)
    res = sorted([str(x) for x in nums], key=cmp, reverse=True)
    return ''.join(res)

sol = Solution()
assert '232302' == sol.largestNumber([230, 23, 2])
```

edit: this is using Python 3.7.4 btw

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I just realized I'm misusing the cmp function. It's supposed to return -1, 0, or 1 -- not the element that I determined was the smallest.